# How to restore source-control settings after new install of Domino Deisgner?

Tags: lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

This week I had to completely re-install my Notes Client including Domino Designer (V 9.0.1 FP10 HF282, to be exact). Before the re-install I did a backup of some crucial files and folders including workspace. Afterwards I was able to restore much of my previous setup like local OSGi plugins. What I had completely forgotten was the fact that I had setup a local file sync for source control.

Before I go through the pain of re-wiring everything from Domino Designer via local file system into our gitlab repository I'm wondering whether it is possible to restore everything needed from my \workspace\ backup.

Anyone ever done this? Which files and folders would I need to recover?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out myself, was looking in the wrong place as apparently this is *not* part of the client's workspace.
Easiest way to re-bind my local repositories to Notes databases seems to be:

- switch to Java perspective, then import the local repo as an existing
  project
- switch back to Domino Designer perspective and link database to the existing project

Please let me know if there's an easier way

*Update:* My first idea obviously wasn't wrong either: those local projects are indeed stored inside \Data\Workspace. Need to backup / restore this folder:
\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources.projects.
Thanks to @PaulWithers for an old blog post dealing with [backing up working sets](https://www.intec.co.uk/restoring-domino-designer-including-working-sets/)